# App update (complete redesign) maintaining existing core data info... possible?

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode9

I have an old app on the app store that needs to be updated to work with iOS11 and the notch. It's an older project so there's a LOT of problems and it would be much easier to just rebuild it (it's a simple app). The original app was built with **Swift2** and **Xcode7** I believe.

If I recreate the core data "structure" exactly as it was in the old app and then upload the new app as an "update"... is there any possibility it will migrate the core data from the old app to the new one? As I understand it, unless I make changes to the structure of the core data itself (add new entities, etc) it **should** just migrate automatically, but it's the "whole new app" that has me confused here.

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the Core Data model files from the old project to the new one?

Comment: I can't seem to find any good guides on that process. Most say to simply copy the model to the new project but I'm not exactly sure how to do that properly.

Comment: I was able to get the core data model transferred over no problem but it doesn't persist the existing data. The model works fine but the data from the previous app doesn't show up.

Comment: Also make sure the new app is set up to store the Core Data sqlite in the same place in the filesystem that the old app stored it. And add a new data model version if you make any changes to the data model in the new app. If you do that it should find and migrate the old database when you update, no problem.